# Calling CPP Constructor with overloaded >> operator

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading

I'm pretty new to c++, and i was wondering if the following is possible:

consider you have

```
class Client {
public:
    Client(string firstname, string lastname);
// ...
}
```

could you overload the `>>` operator to generate a new object with the input you just gave in?

like

```
istream& operator>> (istream& is, Client* client) {
    cout << "First Name: ";
    is >> client->firstName;
    cout << "Last Name: ";
    is >> client->lastName;
    return is;
}
```

?

what would be the correct way to create an object based on user input using overloaded >> operator and how would you do it?
if i want to do it like this, i would have to write

```
Client* client;
cin >> client;
```

but at that moment, the client is already created...

thanks

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense. And while you could write an operator that returns your value, you lose the chaining ability; at this point it's better to just write `istream&` constructor

Comment: why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: Because it wants a pointer to an object as well, IOW doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: yeah but that's part of the question. how would i create a new object with this? like cin >> newClient; that fills the constructor with user input

Comment: You need to declare `newClient` first, that's the point. A new name can't be introduced in the `>>` expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this (the client pointer needs to be passed by reference, then read to temp variables and create the client):

```
istream& operator >> (istream& is, Client * &client) {
    string firstname, lastname;
    cout << "First Name: ";
    is >> firstname;
    cout << "Last Name: ";
    is >> lastname;
    client = new Client(firstname, lastname);
    return is;
}

Client* client;
cin >> client;
// use client
delete client;
```

But I wouldn't recommend that in general. The cleaner way is to have

```
istream& operator >> (istream& is, Client &client) {
    cout << "First Name: ";
    is >> client.firstname;
    cout << "Last Name: ";
    is >> client.lastname;
    return is;
}

Client client;
cin >> client;
// use client
// client destroyed on scope exit
```

Comment: Yeah, or `Client client(std::cin)`. Or `Client client(Client::constructFromInputStream(std::cin))`.

Comment: would the first one work without `Client client;`?
then: how? `cin >> client;` and it would be created inside the operator?

Comment: @user3787706: Yes. But you need a `Client* client_ptr`.